# Retrieve Crash Reports and Logs in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have released my application in App store. How to trace the error logs and crash report happened from the end user? Is the NSLog or NSException in the code to find the trace?

Can you please advice on how to implement in the code logic to trace the logs efficiently ?

Is there any open source API Available to trace the logs in the application ?

Comment: Apple widely supports to collect the crash reports (if the user granted it on their own device) and you are able to download them via iTunes Connect's site (under the _Crash Report_ section).

Comment: Please check my answer. . Don't put down vote. . May i know what's the reason ? You guys don't understand the question. .

Answer (score 1):

Here are the ways to integrate the open source api to analyze the Crash Report Logs in IOS :

**JIRA Mobile Connect Reference (Open Source) :**

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Mobile+Connect
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Mobile+Connect+FAQ#JIRAMobileConnectFAQ-HowmuchdoesJIRAMobileConnectcost?
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Enabling+JIRA+Mobile+Connect
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlDyjA37rjU - Video explanation to configure JIRA.

**PL Crash Reporter (Open Source) :**

http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html

http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html

JIRA using the PL Crash Reporter.

**Hockey App(3rd party Paid application) :**

Features : http://hockeyapp.net/features/

Atlassian Integration : https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/HockeyApp+Third-Party+Integration

Answer (score 0):

Our application use crashlytics to track whenever application crashes.

It helps to improve quality of the application

Should use feedback from your application to allow user feedback

Comment: What is your application ?